# Apply a func to generate a new colum based on value of other colums in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to get the avg. time spent on page by dividing the (total) time spent on page by 'pageviews'

Part of the dataframe:

```
>      Page          Month  Pageviews   Users   Time on Page (HH:MM:SS)
> 0 /Products/..    201503  1925        1006    27:43:45
> 1 /Products/..    201502  1811        930     26:32:33
> 2 /Products/..    201504  1781        969     28:05:38
```

I wrote a func to turn (HH:MM:SS) into seconds and divide the generated number (x) by # pageviews (y)

```
def avg_time_on_page(x,y):
    return (60*60*int(x.split(':')[0])+60*int(x.split(':')[1])+int(x.split(':')[2]))/y
```

Trying to create a col called 'AvgTimeOnPage' by using the following code

```
df['AvgTimeOnPage'] = df[['Time on Page','Pageviews']].apply(avg_time_on_page, axis=1)
```

Got the error msg

```
TypeError: ('avg_time_on_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)', u'occurred at index 0')
```

My question is -

When I 'apply' that function to both 'Time on Page' & 'Pageviews' columns, wouldn't it take the value from both columns as the argument and return one value, which is 'AvgTimeOnPage', as the output? I don't quite understand the error msg saying '1' arg is given, instead of '2'

Can someone explain why it did not work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the column is a timedelta:

```
In [11]: df.iloc[:, 4]  # lazy way to access column with long name...
Out[11]:
0    27:43:45
1    26:32:33
2    28:05:38
Name: Time on Page (HH:MM:SS), dtype: object

In [12]: pd.to_timedelta(df.iloc[:, 4])
Out[12]:
0   1 days 03:43:45
1   1 days 02:32:33
2   1 days 04:05:38
Name: Time on Page (HH:MM:SS), dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Note: you may want to set this column.

Then you can divide:

```
In [13]: pd.to_timedelta(df.iloc[:, 4]) / df['Pageviews']
Out[13]:
0   00:00:51.857142
1   00:00:52.762562
2   00:00:56.787198
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I did try your solution and it worked. But my question is: why does the function not take two arguments (time on page/x & pageviews/y) and output a new value AvgTimeOnPage as previously  defined?

Comment: @Yumi Ah, I see, apply takes ONE argument (which is a row/Series) and you access the column as `x['Time on Page']` inside the apply. Passing as (x,y) doesn't work - I suspect the second argument is used as some kind of flag.